# OSX 10.9 Time Machine backup to NAS

Tags: macos, time-machine, osx-mavericks

I recently upgraded from 10.6.8 to 10.9. on snow leopard i was able to make time machine backups over the network to my nas, i think i had to tweak some settings but i dont recall what i did.

now that i upgraded to mavericks, i cannot do backups to my nas using time machine.

my question is, what do i have to do to allow time machine backups over the network in 10.9?

i tried looking for solutions online but did not find anything relating to mavericks.

Comment: nothing for this?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me..

Try the following:
- Open a finder window and choose "connect to server"
- type afp://"x.x.x.x -> IP numbers of your NAS"/TMBackup
- then put in the Username and PW of the TimeMachine User and press Enter.

Afterwards this new connected server should appear in the TimeMachine settings as a valid TimeMachine network drive.

Thanks to the link below.

http://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=85065&start=15